# Ubuntu Core as Hyper-V virtual machine image

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu-core, hyper-v

As Ubuntu Core can be installed on an Intel® NUC, is there any possbility to make it run as Hyper-V virtual machine to play around with it?

Comment: ok, will do but why there as it Ubuntu Core is an Ubuntu product.

Comment: That’s a good question for [meta] actually! The [on-topic help page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) links to https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours, which only lists the desktop flavours.

Comment: @dessert We have supported Ubuntu Core for the entire duration of its existence, all the way back to when it was called Snappy Core. We have numerous questions about it, over 500 of which are in the [tag:ubuntu-core] tag. We have [meta discussions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12357/tag-synonym-request-snappy-ubuntu-core) about proper tagging for it. If in spite of this you believe Ubuntu Core (and presumably also Ubuntu Server?) is or should be off-topic because it is not listed as a desktop flavor, I think the burden of proof is on you to consult the community on meta.

Comment: @EliahKagan Wow, I totally missed that, and retracted my vote now. Why is the on-topic help page so misleading in this point? You’re totally right, if you read this page you must come to the conclusion that even a question about Ubuntu Server is not a question “that you may ask”! We really should do something about that.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully installed it in Hyper-V.

I followed [Install Ubuntu Core on the Intel® NUC | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/intel-nuc) whereby I used a virtual disk do get `dawson-uc18-m7-20190122-10.img.xz`into the VM. 
I created a virtual disk as described in [How to Attach and Copy files from a VHD in Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/attach-copy-files-vhd-windows-10/) 
mounted it in Win 10, copied the downloaded files, set it offline to include it in the VM as described on [How to Access Local and USB Hard Drives In Your Hyper-V Virtual Machine](https://www.howtogeek.com/223193/how-to-access-local-and-usb-hard-drives-in-your-hyper-v-virtual-machine/).
Afterwards, I started the VM, went online and browsed to the tutorial to copy the commands, run the commands and done.

There are only two things:

- do a hard restart, restarting via the live-image won't work
- the username for ssh is given in your user account, it is not your email.

Comment: Please do not send [same answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1261434/264781) to different questions. Instead mark the other question as a duplicate of the one you send an answer to.